# 8 Predefined binary convolutional filters in CNN - Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, convolution

I'm trying to do the following in Tensorflow:

[I need this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0A3t.png)

For this I have done the following so far:

```
def new_weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.05))

# From here down is another function
shape = [3, 3, 1, 8,]

H = [
    [[0,  1, 0,],[0, -1, 0,],[0,  0, 0,],],
    [[0,  0, 1,],[0, -1, 0,],[0,  0, 0,],],
    [[0,  0, 0,],[0, -1, 1,],[0,  0, 0,],],
    [[0,  0, 0,],[0, -1, 0,],[0,  0, 1,],],
    [[0,  0, 0,],[0, -1, 0,],[0,  1, 0,],],
    [[0,  0, 0,],[0, -1, 0,],[1,  0, 0,],], 
    [[0,  0, 0,],[1, -1, 0,],[0,  0, 0,],],
    [[1,  0, 0,],[0, -1, 0,],[0,  0, 0,],]
]

anchor_weights = tf.reshape(tf.cast(H, tf.float32), shape)

layer = tf.nn.conv2d(input=input,
                     filter=anchor_weights,
                     strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                     padding='SAME')

layer = tf.nn.max_pool(value=layer,
                       ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                       strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                       padding='SAME')

layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)

feature_maps = layer

shape = [1, 1, 8, 1]

v = tf.cast(new_weights(shape), tf.float32)

# To put all together
layer = tf.nn.conv2d(input=feature_maps,
                     filter=v,
                     strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                     padding="SAME")
```

But when I go to print the anchor_weights and the feature_maps I do this in response.

[anchor_weights e feature_maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ5W5.png)

For me it seems to be completely wrong about what I need that would be like the first image I showed you.

I do not know how to fix this, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have wrong order of elements in `H` array. You filled `H` as `[8,3,3]` tensor. Then you use `tf.reshape`, this changes shape of tensor, but doesn't swap elements. You need something like this:

```
H = [
     [ 
      [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]],
      [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
      [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
     ],
     [ 
      [[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]],
      [[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]],
      [[ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
     ],
     [ 
      [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]],
      [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]],
      [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
     ]
    ]
anchor_weights = tf.cast(H, tf.float32)
```

Comment: I got this! This works perfectly! Thank you! But could you try to explain to me exactly what works? And where exactly does it work? (that is, where this change happens)  

And is there any way I can print the H and view it as vector with 8 matrices 3x3?

Comment: You use tensor `H` as kernel of `tf.conv2d`, the kernel must have shape `[3,3,1,8] = [kernel_w, kernel_h, inp_ch, out_ch]`. `tf.reshape` doesn't change order of tensors elements, only description of the shape.